# rhandsontable wrong format date display when formatting dates

Tags: r, shiny, rhandsontable

I have a simple rhandsontable shiny app showing dates, but dates are not shown properly.

```
    library(rhandsontable)   
    library(magrittr)

    DF_na = data.frame(integer = c(NA, 2:10), 
                               logical = c(NA, rep(TRUE, 9)), 
                               character = c(NA, LETTERS[1:9]),
                               factor = c(NA, factor(letters[1:9])),
                               date = c(NA, seq(from = Sys.Date(), by = "days", 
                                                length.out = 9)),
                               stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

            DF_na$factor_ch = as.character(DF_na$factor)
            DF_na$date_ch = c(NA, as.character(seq(from = Sys.Date(), by = "days", 
                                                   length.out = 9)))

            rhandsontable(DF_na) %>%
 hot_col("date", dateFormat = "DD/MM/YYYY", type = "date")
```

The format display is wrong. Dates are shown as MM-DD-YY in my app but i need to be DD-MM-YY

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Format the dates in R:

```
x <- format(seq(from = Sys.Date(), by = "days", length.out = 9), "%d/%m/%Y")

DF_na = data.frame(integer = c(NA, 2:10), 
                   logical = c(NA, rep(TRUE, 9)), 
                   character = c(NA, LETTERS[1:9]),
                   factor = c(NA, factor(letters[1:9])),
                   date = as.character(c(NA,x)),
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

rhandsontable(DF_na) %>%
  hot_col("date", dateFormat = "DD/MM/YYYY", type = "date")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to this https://github.com/jrowen/rhandsontable/issues/145 issue you have to use a custom date format you have to do the following:

1. Convert the data frame date column to a character
2. Specify the dateFormat in the hot_col specification
3. Convert back from the character string after reading input$table using hot_to_r

The correct code listing to do fix the format is:

```
library(rhandsontable)   
library(magrittr)

DF_na = data.frame(integer = c(NA, 2:10), 
                   logical = c(NA, rep(TRUE, 9)), 
                   character = c(NA, LETTERS[1:9]),
                   factor = c(NA, factor(letters[1:9])),
                   date = c(NA, seq(from = Sys.Date(), by = "days", 
                                    length.out = 9)),
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

DF_na$factor_ch = as.character(DF_na$factor)
DF_na$date_ch = format(as.Date(DF_na$date, origin = "1970-01-01"), "%d/%m/%y")

rhandsontable(DF_na) %>%
  hot_col("date_ch", dateFormat = "DD/MM/YY", type = "date")
```

[image]